# Return Values in one column based on another column values

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to store values from one column of a CSV if another value in the same row equals a user entered value. As of now I can only store the value that is found in the CSV instead of the other column value. Any tips on how catch another column in the same row? this is VB.net

```
Sub CSV()
    Dim meternum As Integer
    Dim Entermet As String
    Entermet = InputBox("Please Enter The Meternum", "Select Start Meter", "", meternum)
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                    FileIO.TextFieldParser(
                      "C:\Consumers.csv")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    If Entermet = currentField Then MsgBox(currentField)
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                        FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: is there an error? does it not work?  the code doesnt quite match the description.  The code will match if ANY value matches rather than if a particular filed value matches.  You might also have type conversion issues depending on what is being searched for.

Comment: Your whole approach to this problem is wrong. If you work with csv use `microsoft ace oledb`. Read that thing into `datatable` and search for whatever values you need with breeze.

Comment: it's a bit heavyweight to use oledb in this instance surely?

Comment: @MikeMiller No. Developing all this is heavy. Using existing functionality is not.

Answer (score 1):

ReadFields returns an array of string, so if you know the position of the 2 columns it should be as easy as doing

```
If currentRow(positionOfColumnToCheck) = Entermet Then
  SavedValue = currentRow(positionOfColumnToSave)
End if
```

But SavedValue would be a list.  So you'd probably want to use a list of tuple or hashtable, to preserve both the value and the Meternum.